# d3js stack chart with simple data

Tags: layout, stack, d3.js

I need a very basic example to create a stack chart like [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/3020685) with a predefined array like this:

```
var data = [[ 1,  4,  2,  7],
            [21,  2,  5, 10],
            [ 1, 17, 16,  6]]
```

Whatever I do ends creating errors. E.g. TypeError: data is undefined. 
Here is my simplified code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js?2.9.5"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var data = [[ 1,  4,  2,  7],
            [21,  2,  5, 10],
            [ 1, 17, 16,  6]];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([0,3]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0])
    .domain([0,25]);

var z = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var stack = d3.layout.stack(data)
      .offset("zero")
      .values(function(d) { return d; })
      .x(function(d, i) { return i; })
      .y(function(d) { return d; });

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y0(function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); });

svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .data(stack)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "layer")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors[i]; });

</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/DyrsK/2/.

Generally I find it easier to permute the input data a little bit to get into the default form that `d3` expects. For this example I took your data and computed the `x`, `y` and `y0` values and then passed that to the default stack layout.

```
var data = [[ 1,  4,  2,  7],
            [21,  2,  5, 10],
            [ 1, 17, 16,  6]];

// permute the data
data = data.map(function(d) { 
    return d.map(function(p, i) { 
        return {x:i, y:p, y0:0};
    });
});
```

I think there is an easier way to do this, but I had trouble with the `out()` function of `d3.layout.stack()` since your input data was a value but the `out()` function expects it to be a reference value. This meant that there wasn't a way to update the values with the computed offsets and so the data being returned by `stack()` was always equal to the input values.

After getting the stack function to work, the rest pretty much followed from the example you linked to:

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack()
      .offset("zero")

var layers = stack(data);

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate('cardinal')
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .y0(function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); });

svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .data(layers)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "layer")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d); })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return colors(i); });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot, my biggest mistake was to use:  return area(d.values); which returned an undefined which got me of the track :-(

Comment: I always check what `d` is referring to by placing a `console.log(d)` inside the functions like `function(d) { console.log(d); return area(d); })`. That way I make sure that I'm accessing the right values.

Comment: It seems that your solution only works well for three columns data. I tried four columns, it displays not as I expect.

Comment: Make sure you update the domain of the Y scale to the new sum of the four columns.